# Where can I change specific store ( territory ) of my iOS Application

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I made my new app in iTunes Connect. I didn't set the specific store, so it's now worldwide. But now ( before I upload my binary ) I would like to change it to my country only ( Hungary ) . I can't find where should I do it. I didn't pressed "Ready to Upload Binary" button yet.

Answer (score 1):

On this app's overview page, click the "Rights and Pricing" button near the right. Then, click on the Specific Territories, and here on Deselect All. Now select only the single country you want to appear in, and hit Save.

Comment: Does this require a new binary to be submitted to the app store ?

Answer (score 1):

clicked : My App - Pricing and Availability -Available in all territories
select you want release country only and then done button press.